# OBS crashes when I try to windows capture

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os

I am currently running on Elementary OS Freya (based on Ubuntu 14.04)

Whenever I try to add window capture, OBS crashes.

```
    :~$ optirun obs
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
info: Processor: 4 logical cores
info: Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
info: Physical Memory: 7894MB Total
info: Kernel Version: Linux 3.16.0-60-generic
info: Distribution: "elementary OS" "0.3.2"
QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
info: OBS 0.13.1 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 44100
    speakers:        2
info: OpenGL version: 3.2.0 NVIDIA 352.63

info: ---------------------------------
info: video settings reset:
    base resolution:   1366x768
    output resolution: 1092x614
    fps:               30/1
    format:            NV12
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: image-source.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: linux-capture.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: linux-decklink.so
libDeckLinkAPI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
info: No blackmagic support
info: Failed to start search for DeckLink devices
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: linux-jack.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: linux-pulseaudio.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: linux-v4l2.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: obs-ffmpeg.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: obs-filters.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: obs-libfdk.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: obs-outputs.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: obs-transitions.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: obs-x264.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: rtmp-services.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: Loading module: text-freetype2.so
info: =====================================================================
info: output 'simple_stream' (rtmp_output) created
info: encoder 'simple_h264_stream' (obs_x264) created
info: AAC encoder bitrate mapping:
     32 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
     64 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
     96 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
    128 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
    160 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
    192 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
    224 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
    256 kbit/s: 'libfdk AAC Encoder' (libfdk_aac)
    288 kbit/s: 'FFmpeg Default AAC Encoder' (ffmpeg_aac)
    320 kbit/s: 'FFmpeg Default AAC Encoder' (ffmpeg_aac)
info: encoder 'simple_aac' (libfdk_aac) created
info: output 'simple_file_output' (ffmpeg_muxer) created
error: Service '' not found
info: service 'default_service' (rtmp_common) created
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 4.0'
error: pulse-input: Sample spec is not valid
error: Failed to create source 'Desktop Audio'!
info: source 'Desktop Audio' (pulse_output_capture) created
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 4.0'
error: pulse-input: Sample spec is not valid
error: Failed to create source 'Mic/Aux'!
info: source 'Mic/Aux' (pulse_input_capture) created
info: source 'Scene' (scene) created
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 172.62 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 1.078 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 0.839 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 142.271 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 0.926 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 106.209 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0.346 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0.106 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 58.886 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitOBSCallbacks: 0.027 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitHotkeys: 0.051 ms
info:      ┣obs_load_all_modules: 17.717 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(image-source.so): 0.005 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-capture.so): 0.736 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-decklink.so): 0.264 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-jack.so): 0.005 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-pulseaudio.so): 0.006 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-v4l2.so): 0.005 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-ffmpeg.so): 0.011 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-filters.so): 0.037 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-libfdk.so): 0.004 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-outputs.so): 0.004 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-transitions.so): 0.008 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-x264.so): 0.009 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(rtmp-services.so): 0.107 ms
info:      ┃ ┗obs_init_module(text-freetype2.so): 0.041 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetOutputs: 0.488 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::CreateHotkeys: 0.023 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitService: 0.055 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitPrimitives: 0.131 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::Load: 7.664 ms
info: =================================================
info: Update check: last known remote version is 0.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing in my opinion is perhaps because of the Graphics driver mismatch or perhaps needing.

Looks like you are using bumblebee (targetting NVIDIA's Optimus technology) to launch.

Try this at your own risk.

First figure out which graphics card you have.

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

That showed me that I'm using " NVIDIA Corporation GF116M [GeForce GT 550M] (rev a1)"
So it is NVIDIA

Then install it from xorg-edgers PPA.  Use the latest version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search nvidia
Find the latest one (at time of this writing was 352)
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352-updates
```

In this process, I got rid of Noveau and installed NVIDIA driver from xorg-edgers PPA.  obs launced good after that.

However there have been screen freezes every now and then and I'm planning to explore using bumblebee on top of this and see if anything changes.

Good luck

Note : installing NVIDIA driver by directly getting from NVIDIA which failed